# Infinite regex match in single line in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to know if it's possible to match one pattern multiple time (the number of match is not know) and extract each occurences for make a compare?

My goal is to find if a vlan is configure on an interface.

I have this file sample (I have trunc it) :

```
interface Ethernet1/16
  shutdown
  switchport access vlan 777
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable

interface Ethernet1/17
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 201
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-69,71-100,110-111,120,153,198,200-366,368-397,400-599,1000-3967,4048-4093
  channel-group 2 mode active

interface Ethernet1/18
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 201
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-69,71-100,110-111,120,153,198,200-366,368-397,400-599,1000-3967,4048-4093
  channel-group 2 mode active

interface Ethernet1/19
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 201
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-69,71-100,110-111,120,153,198,368-397,400-599,1000-3967,4048-4093
  channel-group 2 mode active
```

I have this code for parsing the file and for each interface, I check if I can find the vlan (provided in argument) in a range.

```
REGEX="^interface (.*)"
REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN="^switchport trunk allowed.*(\d+)-(\d+),*"
vlan=$2  

while read line; do

  if [[ $line =~ $REGEX ]]; then      
    ifname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  else
    if [[ $line =~ $REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN ]]; then
        #for each pattern match on this line, I need to check
        if [ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -lt $vlan ] && [ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} -gt $vlan ]; then
          echo "vlan is included in interface $ifname"
        fi
    fi
  fi
done <$1
```

For example, if I looking for the vlan 250, the output will :

> vlan is included in interface Ethernet1/17
>   vlan is included in interface Ethernet1/18

Comment: what do you want to do with `${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -lt $vlan` and `${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -gt $vlan` ? From man bash : `arg1 OP arg2 : OP  is  one  of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic binary operators [...].  Arg1 and arg2  may  be  positive  or negative integers.`

Comment: Could you please provide example for second parameter ($2) ?

Comment: Well, the `REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN="^switchport trunk allowed.*(\d+)-(\d+),*"` is wrong as `.*` is too greedy and the first `(\d+)` will only have `1` if there is `21`. You may try `REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN="^switchport trunk allowed.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)"`

Comment: $2 is a vlan : 250 for example.
if I take is line :   `switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-69,71-100,110-111,120,153,198,200-366,368-397,400-599,1000-3967,4048-4093`

I need to check if 250 is included in this line, and it is because we have a range `200-366`.

But I don't know how to check each match (XXX-YYY)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you're right about the regex, but now, I need to find every [^0-9]([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) match because I need to verify that $vlan is GT  group1 and LT group2

Comment: @Rian: you approach isn't the good one and regex will not help to know if a number is in a range or not. You need to extract systematically all ranges for each interface, I don't see an other way.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes I think about it. Extract all ranges, and check for each range, but I don't know how to extract them. I thought I can do it whith regex.

Comment: @Rian: I'm not a bash expert but you can select the line with its beginning using a pattern and then you can split it on commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract all the ranges and test them one by one. No need to extract them with a regex pattern, you can split the line using the IFS. With my poor bash capabilities:

```
REGEX_INTERFACE="^interface (.*)"
REGEX_SWITCHPORT="^switchport trunk allowed vlan "
vlan=$2

while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $REGEX_INTERFACE ]]; then
        ifname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ $line =~ $REGEX_SWITCHPORT ]]; then
        OLDIFS="$IFS"
        IFS=','
        for elt in ${line:30}; do
            IFS='-' read -r start end <<< "$elt"
            if [[ "$start" -eq "$vlan" || "$end" -ge "$vlan" && "$start" -lt "$vlan" ]]; then
                echo "vlan is included in interface $ifname"
                break
            fi
        done
        IFS="$OLDIFS"
    fi
done <$1
```

Comment: I've done something like that thanks to you :
   `ranges=$(echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} | tr "," "\n")`
    and 
      `for range in $ranges  do`

Comment: @Rian: I'm trying to do it without using an array.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work :

```
REGEX="^interface (.*)"
REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN="^[ ]*switchport trunk allowed vlan (.*)"
vlan=$2

while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ $REGEX ]]
  then
    ifname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  fi

  if [[ $line =~ $REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN ]]
  then
      old=$IFS
      IFS=","
      for range in ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      do
        if [[ $vlan -ge ${range%-*} && $vlan -le ${range#*-} ]]
        then
          echo "vlan is included in interface $ifname"
        fi
      done
      IFS=$old
  fi
done < $1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done like that :

```
REGEX="^interface (.*)"
REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN="switchport trunk allowed vlan (.*)"
REGEX_RANGE="([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)"
REGEX_PO="channel-group.*"

if [[ $line =~ $REGEX_TRUNKRANGEVLAN ]]; then
  #for each pattern match on this line, I need to check
  ranges=$(echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} | tr "," "\n")

  for range in $ranges
  do
    if [[ $range =~ $REGEX_RANGE ]]; then
      if [ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -le $vlan ] && [ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} -ge $vlan ]; then
        vlancontained=true
        mode="TRUNK RANGE"
      fi
    else
      if [ $range != "none" ] && [ $range -eq $vlan ]; then
        vlancontained=true
        mode="TRUNK"
      fi
    fi
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly not the prettiest way to do it, certainly not the most efficient way also, but because I put some time writing this command, I'll share it even if your problem is solved :

```
sed -r -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n//g' -e 's/(interface Ethernet)/\n\1/g' |awk '{gsub(",", " ", $15); print "echo "$1"_"$2" "$15}' | sed -r 's#([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)#`seq \1 \2`#ge'
```

What it does is transforming all the interfaces blocks as one line `<interface> <ranges>`and transforming all the ranges on each line on the list of vlans.

ie. if the line is : `<interface> 3-5 7 8-10`
it will transform into : `<interface> 3 4 5 7 8 9 10`

- `-e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n//g'` : Removes all the `\n`
- `-e 's/(interface Ethernet)/\n\1/g'` :  Each `interface Ethernet` will be the start of a new line
- `awk '{gsub(",", " ", $15); print "echo "$1"_"$2" "$15}'` : Replaces the `","` by `" "` and print the `interface Ethernet...` and ranges field. The trick here is the `echo` which will be used on the next sed statement
- `sed -r 's#([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)#`seq \1 \2`#ge'` : Replaces each pattern `XXX-XXX` of vlan range by : `seq XXX XXX`. The `e` flag will then execute the replacement line.

  which will be of the form :

```
echo interface `seq 3 5` 7 `seq 8 10`
```

After that you just need to `grep` the lines where the vlan appears.

I don't think it will be of much use for you now, but I spent too much time on this one to not share it ;)

-- Edit

Some awk script a little more refined :

```
awk '/interface Ethernet[0-9]*\/[0-9]*/{iface=$1" "$2}; /switchport trunk allowed vlan/{ gsub(",", " "); print "echo "iface" \\" ; for(i = 5; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i~/[0-9]*-[0-9]*/) { gsub("-", " ", $i); printf (" `seq %s`", $i) } else { printf (" %s",$i) } ; if (i!=NF){print "\\"} else {print""} } }' /tmp/test.vlan | sh |grep ' 250 ' |cut -d" " -f1,2
```

Comment: Thank you for your share ! 
Another way to do it. It can help me one day for make an only one syntax

Comment: @Rian It kind of bugs me to not provide something a little more refined, so here it is. Just have to change the input file and provide the vlan from a variable : *I edited my answer, because the "`" are a little buggy here*